# Can I change the URL for RSS feed in NetNewsWire?

Tags: rss

Is it possible to change the URL of a RSS feed in NetNewsWire? And if so, how?

I am using NetNewsWire ver. 3.2.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feed URL can only be edited if Google Reader sync is off.

Select the feed in the left column and press ⌘I to bring up the feed info window.  Click on the triangle next to the *URLs* entry and you will get a text box that will allow you to edit the feed URL.  There are a bunch of other setting there that allow you to do things like specify how often a particular feed is updated, how long articles are kept, etc.

[image: NNW Window]

Comment: That field is not editable.

Comment: @Alex It is for me, at least for the feed I checked.

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: I'm using NetNewsWire 3.2.15, and I can edit the Feed URL field. I have always been able to do so, and it works as expected. Is this possibly related to having Google Reader sync enabled (I don't)?

Comment: @Kevin Reid That is indeed true, if the sync is disabled, you can edit the Feed URL field. I just tested it.